# Need: javascript dropdown replacement widget

Tags: jquery, extjs, yui, drop-down-menu, widget

I need to address the following problem:

- In IE the dropdown body is what dictates the width of the dropdown. If i set dropdown width to 100px then the body will get cut off if its wider.

Last time (4 months ago) i looked for a suitable widget i found the following problems

1. Not all dropdown keyboard shortcuts supported: up/down arrows, press letter to go to option starting with that letter (this is a **deal breaker**)
2. Most widgets would transform an existing widget, which is an unnecessary step for me. (though not a deal breaker)

question: Has there been any new dropdown widgets out or any that i have missed that i should consider. I use jquery, but i will look at any framework.

Answer (score 1):

RAD ComboBox?

http://www.telerik.com/products/aspnet-ajax/combobox.aspx

Comment: Interesting. Ill keep this one on my radar.